# How to include a .js file (for a game) in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get into web development, and I am currently building a website that will showcase all of my personal projects.

That being said, I am experimenting with Node.js, and I am trying to have my web server render an html file that has css styling, and a .js file attached to it. It's a game I created. I changed my html file to an ejs file, and I put the css file in the views folder, however, I cannot figure out how to attach the .js that makes the page interactive to the .ejs file. Everytime I try, Node keeps giving me an error, "cannot GET" the file. Do I have to turn the .js file that controls the game's logic into module, and bring it in that way? I am a completely newbie to Node.js, so please excuse me if I sound a little vague.

I am using the Express.js framework, by the way.

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/home", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.get("/ColorGame", function(req, res) {
  res.render("colorGame.ejs");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server activated and listening on port 3000");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorGame.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Great
      <br>
      <span id = "colorDisplay">RGB</span>
      <br>
      Guessing Game</h1>
    <div id = "stripe">
      <button type="button" id = "reset">New Colors!</button>
      <span id = "message"></span>
      <button type="button" class = "selected" id = "easyButton">Beginner</button>
      <button type="button" class = "selected" id = "mediumButton">Intermediate</button>
      <button type="button" class = "selected" id = "hardButton">Expert</button>
    </div>
    <div id = "container">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src = "/colorGameLogic.js"></script>
</html>
```

[This is what my folder structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiwK5.png)

Comment: It's very hard to help with a coding problem if there's no code.

Comment: I think you need to do some research and learn how webpages/sites work. W3C is a good place to start https://www.w3schools.com/. Also since there's no ejs in the code you've posted, start by just serving the file as a static file.

Comment: I know how to render the file on the screen without the javascript. If I exclude the script tag from the .ejs file, it works fine. The .ejs file renders successfully with the styling included. I also know how to have a static .html file render with .css, and .js --That isn't my issue. My issue is how do I do this with Node.js, specifically?

Comment: i don't get it at all...do you want the `game logic` to be executed in the browser or on your node server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js file needs to be in your public folder